# "disk drive for /configdrive is not ready yet or not present" on boot

Tags: boot, server

My hosting company moved my virtual server to a "public cloud". After this, my server is down.  When I try to boot (using my hosting company's web interface), it tells me:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/vda1: clean, 380025/5242880 files, 18180399/20971264 blocks
mount: according to mtab, tmpfs is already mounted on /dev/shm

mountall: mount  /dev/shm [306] terminated with status 1
udevd[294]: specified group 'lp' unknown

swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
mountall: swapon /swapfile [437] terminated with status 255
mountall: Problem activating swap: /swapfile
swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
mountall swapon /swapfile [438] terminated with status 255
mountall: Problem activating swap: /swapfile
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/aliases, it will be ignored in a future release
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/aliases, it will be ignored in a future release
WARNING: All config files need .conf: /etc/modprobe.d/aliases, it will be ignored in a future release
The disk drive for /configdrive is not ready yet or not present.
Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

I don't know if pressing S will screw up anything.  If I press M, I'm not sure what to do after that.

Suggestions are appreciated.

FYI, when I boot, it first shows me the following.  Then it shows the above.

```
             GNU GRUB  version 1.99-21ubuntu3.19

Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-54-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-54-generic (recovery mode)
Previous Linus versions
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

I selected the first line: Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-54-generic

I have Ubuntu version 12.04.

Comment: 12.04 reaches end of life in a month or two, so you should probably just rebuild the system anyhow using 16.04.  You also should get support from your hosting company.  Unless you have some idea why you have the system configured to mount something in `/configdrive`, which is not a standard directory.

Comment: Enter `S` to skip mounting. Edit your question to show the `terminal` output of `cat /etc/fstab`